# R Shiny / Flex Dashboard is very slow post running it

Tags: r

I have an excel file with 400 000 rows. I have used this file in my application. I know the file is huge so the app is slow. Is there any alternate way to deal with this? Like can we out excel data into online database and then read it?

Comment: Are you reading the excel file once upon load or every time a query is updated? Is the file too large to hold in RAM? Is there a way to pre-process a summarized version? Are there extensive calculations that might benefit from using `data.table`? Hard to help without much more information about your specific use.

Comment: I am trying in flexdashboard so the working should happen within app only. I have read the excel file inside the app only.

Comment: The solution on how to tackle this dataset will vary with your use-case. Without further information it will be hard to give any advice on what to do. In any case, this site may not be ideal venue for this. Something about persistent storage has been discussed here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use a MongoDB, this service https://cloud.mongodb.com gives 500 MB database free, so you could use online database for your app. I'm using a `mongolite` package for connecting to MongoDB Cloud. Here is user manual to `mongolite`: https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/

Also you can read this article about connecting data for shiny apps: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Comment: ok got it. Since my is in flexdashboard, the working should happen inside the app only. I think your solution was to store the data in the server and then fetching it right? But anyways the working should happen in R only right?

Comment: You can connect some external storage eg MongoDB, fetch data and then work with data like you work with it using excel file.